# Find count of items from all tables in SQL Server database (filter tables based on column name)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to find the total number of distinct items from a particular column (named `Ticker`) from all tables in the database.

How can I achieve this?. This is what I want:

```
Table_name  |  Column | Total_Tickers
------------+---------+---------------
Table_1     | ticker  |    500
Table_2     | ticker  |    100 
Table_3     | ticker  |   5000
.
.
```

I know I've got to use `sp_MSForEachTable` but I'm not sure how to filter those tables that do not have a `Ticker` column at all.

This is what I've tried:

```
create table #counts
(
    table_name varchar(255),
    ticker_count int
)

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable @command1='INSERT #counts (table_name, ticker_count) 
SELECT ''?'', COUNT(ticker) FROM ? ',
@whereand = 'AND ''?'' IN (Select * from information_schema.columns where 
column_name = ''%ticker%'')'

SELECT table_name, ticker_count 
FROM #counts 
ORDER BY table_name, ticker_count DESC

DROP TABLE #counts
```

It doesn't recognize the `COUNT(ticker)` on the 7th line since I'm not able to filter the tables!

I'd appreciate any pointers on this. Thanks

Comment: Don't bother with sp_MSForEachTable. Just use information_schema.columns to find all tables with the 'ticker' column, and generate dynamic SQL to select distinct counts from each table into a temporary table, and then finally select distinct from that temporary table. That'll give you all distinct values from all tables with a ticker column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much easier approach

```
use your_databasename --replace with your database name
go
DECLARE @sql         VARCHAR(max)= '',
        @column_name SYSNAME = 'ticker'

SET @sql = Stuff((SELECT ' union all select Table_name = '''+ table_name + ''',[Column] = ''' + column_name
                         + ''',Total_Tickers = count(distinct '+ column_name + ') from '
                         + Quotename(table_catalog) + '.'+ Quotename(table_schema) + '.'+ Quotename(table_name)
                  FROM   information_schema.columns
                  WHERE  column_name = @column_name
                  FOR xml path('')), 1, 11, '') -- stuff is used to remove the first union all
--SELECT @sql

EXEC (@sql)
```

Since tables has to be filtered based on column name, I don't think `msforeachtable` would be helpful here.

Comment: I'm getting "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'SecurityContract'.". Not sure what this means!

Comment: @KshitijG - Are you sure that you copy pasted the exact query ? because we are pulling the tables only when `ticker` column exists!!

Comment: Yes, I did!. Its exact

Comment: Thanks for updating but it didn't work unfortunately!. Same error:
" Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'SecurityContract'.
"